# Is it possible to center and zoom embed PDF content

Tags: html, pdf, embed

I have many problems working with PDF file inside webpage...

Is it possible to programmatically control (center, zoom, etc.) embed PDF content inside the webpage. I prefer PHP, JS or Python, but any other solution would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem, but still not find the answer.

Answer (score -1):

How are you embedding the PDF file inside your webpage - is it within an iframe, or are you using a library such as [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/markup/)?

If you are using a particular tool or library (or adopt that option), it should let you specify some options. For example, PDFObject allows the following options:

> Options include zoom level, jumping to a page number, highlighting search terms, and selecting which toolbars will be visible.

If you are simply displaying the PDF content inside an iframe, perhaps you can try CSS options like `style="zoom:100%"` and `align="center"`?

If you need further help, could you be more specific as to what your current solution is, and provide a JSFiddle? There's a more general question here - [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html).